# Spring cloud config cloud without inheriting from parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I've started with spring cloud config and took this simple example from docs as basis: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_client_side_usage

My server works fine as well the client when I use as independent maven projects

However I'm working in a multi module maven project where my root parent module inherits from spring boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

So my child modules (for instance spring config server, as well different clients) inherits from my parent and each one declares the needed spring boot/cloud dependencies.

Here is the trouble, when I inherit from my parent the client config services cannot fetch config anymore. Here is the explanation on spring cloud config:

```
To use these features in an application, you can build it as a Spring Boot application that depends on spring-cloud-config-client (for an example, see the test cases for the config-client or the sample application). The most convenient way to add the dependency is with a Spring Boot starter org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config. There is also a parent pom and BOM (spring-cloud-starter-parent) for Maven users and a Spring IO version management properties file for Gradle and Spring CLI users
```

So my question is how I can still use multi maven module with my spring client config services? Without directly inheriting from spring-boot-starter-parent?

Here my parent service reduced for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.nicolas</groupId>
  <artifactId>micro-services</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>micro-services</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>produtos</module>
    <module>configserver</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version> ${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

and here how I wish i could use in the child service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.nicolas</groupId>
    <artifactId>micro-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>produtos</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>produtos</name>
  <description>Produtos</description>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Of course I change the above, declaring all the dependencies and repositories again, inheriting from spring boot parent, it works:

```
2018-12-19 19:14:41.169  INFO 17000 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
```

But I don't think I should be re-declaring all dependencies again, pls let me know if anyone has faced that. Thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent):

You will still need the spring cloud dependency management section in your parent as well as the boot one below.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```